# LC3 show a custom prompt for the character input trap

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to make a subroutine to output a custom prompt for the user to input a number.

The IN trap routine normally says `Input a character>`. I need to get it to say
`Please enter a number between 0 and 9:`

Currently I have this:

```
.ORIG x3000
JSR SAVE ; THIS WILL JUMP TO SUBROUTINE TO SAVE CURRENT REGISTER CONTENTS
SAVE   ST R7, x3031 ;SAVES REGISTER VALUE INTO THE ADDRESS 
ST R3, x3030 ;SAVES REGISTER VALUE INTO THE ADDRESS 
ST R2, X302F ;SAVES REGISTER VALUE INTO THE ADDRESS
ST R1, X302E ;SAVES REGISTER VALUE INTO THE ADDRESS 
LD R0, ten ;LOADS TEN FILL VALUE
JSR check
LEA R1, msg1
LDR R0, R1, #0
BRz error
JMP check
ADD R1, R1, #1
check ST R7, X300D
LDI R3, dsr
BRzp x300D
STI R0, ddr
LD R7, x300D
RET
ten .FILL x000A
dsr .FILL xFE04
ddr .FILL xFE06
msg2 .STRINGZ "Enter a number (0 - 9) to subtract from the first number:
msg1 .STRINGZ "Please enter a number between 0 and 9:

.END
```

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].  If you want people to debug your code, you should say what it actually does do, not just what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

1. Creating a subroutine for saving register contents won't work.
   If you call this subroutine within another subroutine you will clobber R7 and thus have no way of exiting your subroutine.  Its best to just have that code be part of your subroutine.
2. ST RX, ADDR will not work.  The offsets for ST/LD are only 9 bits. The proper usage is to create a label for space for saving your register. Similar to the label "ten" in your code.
3. The JMP instruction is used incorrectly.  JMP only takes a register not a label, You shouldn't to use JMP for writing a subroutine.  The most common occurrence of a JMP is the RET instruction which allows you to return from a subroutine.  If you want to jump to some code unconditionally then BR should be used instead.
4. You should only use JSR to call subroutines.  I see it being used to jump to locations "JSR check" for instance.  If you need to jump to a location unconditionally use BR instead.

The steps to write a subroutine should be done as follows

`SUBR
; save used registers
; do computation
; restore used registers
; ret`

For instance a subroutine that prints out the single digit integer in R0 (without any error checking) would be as follows

`PRINT_SINGLE_DIGIT
  ST R7, R7SAVE ; out is a trap so r7 is clobbered we should save it.
  ST R0, R0SAVE ; save R0.
  ADD R0, R0, 15
  ADD R0, R0, 15
  ADD R0, R0, 15
  ADD R0, R0, 3
  OUT
  LD R0, R0SAVE
  LD R7, R7SAVE ; restore R7
  RET
  R0SAVE .blkw 1
  R7SAVE .blkw 1`